# Is there a way to define a Lie derivative of a connection?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, connections, applied-mathematics

I've been reading a little bit about the definition of symmetries on General Relativity, and they are related with the concept of *Killing vector*, i.e., vectors along which the Lie derivative of the metric vanishes $\mathcal{L}_X g =0$.

However, afaik the most symmetric geometrical object is the Ricci tensor ([see the post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/123187/25356)), and the a vector $X$ satisfying $\mathcal{L}_X \text{Ric} = 0$ is known as a *collineation* of the Ricci tensor.

I'd like to know whether is possible to define a sort of Lie derivative for a (general) connection, or a way to somehow define the symmetries of a connection.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Of course, yes. Lie derivative  is defined for any geometric object (= when it is defined what happends when we change a coordinate system): take the flow  $\phi_t$ of the vector field,   consider the pullback $\phi_t^*\Gamma$  of  your geometric object $\Gamma$ and define Lie derivative  as the $\tfrac{d}{dt}$-derviative at $t=0$ of  $\phi_t^*\Gamma$.

For affine connection its Lie derivative is an (1,2)-tensor field. It is because derivative is more or less the same as difference and difference of two connections is a (1,2)-tensor field.

Of course if the Lie derivative of a connection is zero then the connection is presered by the flow  so you vector field is a symmetry of the connection.

Of course there exists an algebraic  formula for the Lie derivative in   terms of the components of an object in the coordinates ($\sim$ Christoffel symbols, for example), components of the  vector field, and their first derivatives. I do not remember this formula by hart but Maples DifferentialGeometry package knows it. It is a sum of  two terms, the first part is the usual formula of the Lie derivative for a (1,2)-tensorfield and the other part is something like the vector field plugged in the curvature.

Answer (score 3):

I was expecting the Lie derivative of a connection to be another connection but Vladimir's answer about the difference of two connections being a tensor makes a lot of sense. I would say a coordinate free algebraic formula for the Lie derivative of a connection is:

$\left(\mathcal{L}_{X}\nabla \right)_{Y}Z:=\mathcal{L}_{X}\left( \nabla_{Y}Z\right)-\nabla_{\mathcal{L}_{X}Y}Z-\nabla_{Y}\mathcal{L}_{X}Z$.

This is just the formula for the Lie derivative of a tensor and in this case it does give a $C^{\infty}(M)$-linear object in the variables $Y$ and $Z$. Since this is a tensor field probably a better notation would be

$\left(\mathcal{L}_{X}\nabla\right)\left( Y,Z \right)$.

Answer (score 2):

[This tweet](https://twitter.com/TimHenke9/status/1581009323400253440) lead me to try to simplify Luis's answer.  A nicer formula is given by:
$$(Y,Z)\mapsto [X,\nabla_YZ]-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z-\nabla_Y([X,Z])
$$
$$=R(X,Y)Z+[X,\nabla_YZ]-\nabla_X\nabla_YZ+\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_Y([X,Z])$$
$$=R(X,Y)Z+\nabla_Y(T(X,Z))-T(X,\nabla_YZ)-\nabla_{\nabla_YZ}X+\nabla_Y\nabla_ZX$$
$$=R(X,Y)Z+\nabla_Y(T(X,Z))-T(X,\nabla_YZ)-\nabla^2_{Y,Z}X$$
where $R(X,Y)Z=\nabla_X\nabla_YZ-\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$ is the contracted [Riemann curvature tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor), $T(X,Y)=\nabla_{X}Y-\nabla_{Y}X-[X,Y]$ is the [torsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_tensor), and $\nabla^2_{Y,Z}$ is the [second covariant derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_covariant_derivative).

If the connection is torsion-free, then this simplifies to $R(X,Y)Z-\nabla^2_{Y,Z}X$.